# Suggestions for a good IDE for DB2

Tags: db2

I know, I know... it's a horrible fate but I am forced to work in an environment with DB2 on the back end. OK just kidding but the truth is I do like MSSQL's data studio a lot, and well IBM's tool is sorda crummy in my opinion... I was using the free version of Toad but I just got a new 64bit machine which is nice and all but there isn't a free version of Toad that I can find for win7 64.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a good IDE to use with DB2? Being a developer I really just do a lot of looking at the DB structure and querying to see what I get back and how I want to get things back etc...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 4):

we use [SQuirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) a java based database client

Comment: and comes in a zip file (no need to install or have admin rights) works on windows and linux. Thanks for the introduction

Answer (score 1):

[DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com) is fairly excellent and has a generous evaluation period.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer I like WinSQL from Synametrics a lot. For me this is the best tool available on the market and works with all major databases: http://www.synametrics.com/SynametricsWebApp/WinSQL.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IBM Optim Data Studio, and it is based on Eclipse, so it could be integrated with many existent plugins for this IDE
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/

And it is free.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [QMF For Windows](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.qmf.doc.intro%2Fdsqa2mst05.htm). But I am not in a position to say it is the best tool

From http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.qmf.doc.intro/gc187443.pdf?noframes=true

> DB2 Query Management Facility (QMF) is a tightly integrated, powerful, and reliable tool that performs query and reporting for IBM’s DB2 relational database management system family.